# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/react' in '/Users/<user-name>/Documents/gift-test/client'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-redux, webpack-dev-server

So for my project (using React and Redux), I keep having errors of 'Module Not Found'. I've google'd & stackoverflow'd several solutions and have seen people say that there's something messed up with my node_modules so I've deleted them, and also npm install (reinstalled).  The error still persists, and I think it has to do with my webpack.config.js file...

I simply just want the build to work properly and the react elements & components to render.

**Errors**

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/react' in '/Users/<user-name>/Documents/gift-test/client'

ERROR in ./client/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/react' in '/Users/<user-name>/Documents/gift-test/client'
 @ ./client/index.js 1:0-41 15:21-26 17:16-21

ERROR in ./client/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/react-dom' in '/Users/<user-name>/Documents/gift-test/client'
 @ ./client/index.js 2:0-50 15:0-6

ERROR in ./client/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/react-redux' in '/Users/<user-name>/Documents/gift-test/client'
 @ ./client/index.js 3:0-54 15:41-49

ERROR in ./client/store.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/redux' in '/Users/<user-name>/Documents/gift-test/client'
 @ ./client/store.js 1:0-68 7:12-23
 @ ./client/index.js

ERROR in ./client/store.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/redux-devtools-extension' in '/Users/<user-name>/Documents/gift-test/client'
 @ ./client/store.js 2:0-78 7:34-53
 @ ./client/index.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    //start at entry
    entry: './client/index.js',
    // devtool: "eval-source-map",
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    //Run these rules on it & go through the loaders
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.svg$/, use: 'svg-inline-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
            { test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                        // plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    }, 
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
        resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'client/index.html'
        })
    ],  
    devServer: {
        publicPath: "/build/",
        proxy: {
            'api':'http://localhost:3000',
        },
    },  
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
}
```

**Beginning part of package.json**

```
{
  "name": "gift-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"nodemon server/server.js\" \"webpack-dev-server --open\" "
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from './node_modules/react';
import { render } from './node_modules/react-dom';
import { Provider } from './node_modules/react-redux';
import App from './App.jsx';
import store from './store.js';
// import styles from './index.css'
// import './index.css';

render(
    <Provider store = {store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**General File Structure**

```
Client
  -Actions
    -actions.js
  -Components
    -component1
    -component2
    -component3
  -Constants
    -actionTypes.js
  -Containers
    -Container1
    -Container2
  -Reducers
    -Reducers (Reducer Logic)
    -Index.js(Combined Reducers)
  
  -App.jsx
  -index.html
  -index.css
  -index.js (Provider & imported store).
  -store.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you need to install react as a dependency. To install just execute this command `npm i react`

ANSWER: import react like this `ìmport React from 'react';`

Comment: try this: ```import React from 'react';``` removing ```./node_modules``` from the import

Comment: It worked tysm! I actually didn't even realize ./node_modules were there..... I swore I didnt add them there lol... what the heck.